# How can we secure our data from DBA?

Tags: sql-server, security

I have very confidential data in my database. I am trying to secure my data from dba.

I am a member of development team. We develop our software and delpoy in a server which has its own dba. We have limited control over the server.

In this scenario how can i deny dba of the server to lookup my data and deny making changes to them.

Is it possible?

Comment: You don't want the database administrator, to administrate the data? Im confused. Is this shared hosting or something?

Comment: @Kyle I think this *is* a legitimate question. The data*base* administrator certainly owns the data*base*, but the *data itself* is a different quantity, which may for example be legally privileged. To use a real-world analogy, the renter of a bank safe deposit box would reasonably expect that they hold the only key to their box - the bank administers the box, but its contents are the renter's.

Comment: In general terms if you can't trust the DBA you're stuffed (in much the same was as you more or less have to trust the dev team) - that's not to say that you can't do things as @Oded suggests to hide the data from view - and that may be desirable regardless for other reasons, but I would worry if the DBA was your first concern.

Comment: @AakashM: the analogy is poor. Assuming not hosting etc... the company owns the data, both DBAs and developers work for the company, company has policies for both DBAs and developers to follow. Simple. I agree with Murph in that they're "stuffed"...

Comment: yeah i am concerned over shared hosting.

Comment: Hmm, for a database with "very confidential data" you shouldn't really be using a shared hosting solution anyways.

Comment: Just saw this question was a couple of years old already, oh well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always encrypt all data that goes into the database.

However, a DBA will have full control on this data - he may not be able to decrypt it, but will be able to read it (in encrypted form), update it and even delete it. Nothing you can do about this.

You really need to rethink things - how can you work with a DBA you cannot trust? Most places will have service agreement that forbid DBAs from doing certain things. You need to rely on this kind of assurance if you don't think your DBAs are trustworthy.

Comment: For updating and deleting can i know who triggered it? either me [my program] or DBA

Comment: @KoolKabin - you can log these actions through triggers on the table. But guess what, a DBA can override those. If it happens on the DataBase, the DBA has control. Nothing you can do about it.

Comment: so sad to hear that my db can be fully altered by DBA in shared hosting  environment.

Comment: @KoolKabin - DBAs have full control of databases. In shared hosting and any other environment. That's their job. Make sure that the hosting agreement does not allow them to look at your data or mess with it (apart for required maintenance work).

Answer (score 5):

Encrypt on the client side, only send and store encrypted data in the database.

In a SQL Server instance, sysadmin can do everything and can not be blocked.

Some thoughts... why is your *team* of developers more trusted then the *single* DBA who I assume is looking after more then one SQL Server box? Can you explain more please?

Comment: Coz I am hosting in shared server.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, you can use database vault option.

Answer (score 1):

there is 2 ways

1
Manual encrypt decrypt with a password
(Only the person who knows the password can encrypt/decrypt)

2
Automated (inside the code) encryption, decryption
(Developer who wrote the code can see the data)

Add CRC to check if data has been altered
Keep backup of senstive data to restore if deleted or altered

Answer (score 0):

Always Encrypted will be the best way to go for Encryption Data encryption and decryption takes place on client side, so data is not revealed in the databases but again DBA will be able to see and delete/edit the data as other users have advised.